# PHPMailer adding multiple emails to BCC from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmailer

In below code, we are first selecting users based on the admin's input from database. Then sending emails to those users. With the code it sends emails to `$mail_news->addAddress('testuser@gmail.com');` test user. But for the bcc part is not working, as it doesn't send any emails to bcc email users.

```
 foreach($email_array  as $news_mail){
          $mail_news->AddBCC($news_mail.";");  
        }
```

This is how we fetch user emails via form & PHP prepare statement with mysqli.

**Here is the main part code:**

```
     if($msn->execute()){
 $msn->store_result();
 $msn->bind_result($news_mail);
 while($msn->fetch()){
 $email_array[] = $news_mail;
 }
      // echo "successful";
          }
        else
        {
            echo "database failed";
        }
        //--Email Sending Starts
            $mail_news = new PHPMailer;
            $mail_news->isSMTP();                             
            $mail_news->Host = EMAIL_HOST; 
            $mail_news->SMTPAuth = true;                          
            $mail_news->Port     = EMAIL_PORT;                  
            $mail_news->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                    
            $mail_news->Username = EMAIL_ADD;               
            $mail_news->Password = EMAIL_PASS;                      
            $mail_news->From = EMAIL_ADD;
            $mail_news->FromName = 'Company Account';
            $mail_news->addAddress('testuser@gmail.com');       
      foreach($email_array  as $news_mail){
          $mail_news->AddBCC($news_mail.";");  
        }
         $mail_news->WordWrap = 50; 
      //   $mail_news->SMTPDebug = 2;
           $mail_news->isHTML(true);                         
           $mail_news->Subject = "".$sub;
           $mail_news->Body    = "".$body;
           $mail_news->AltBody = "".$altbody;

       if(!$mail_news->send()) {
           echo "Failed Sending Emails" ;
         echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail_news->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
       echo "All Email sending completed" ;
   }     

       ?>
        </form>                     
 <?php
     $msn->close();     // Finally closing the database 
       }
 ?>
```

Comment: try by replacing your line `$mail_news->AddBCC($news_mail.";");`  with `$mail_news->addBCC($news_mail);`

Comment: Ok let me try with your suggestion

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I thought ";" was helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the line
    `$mail_news->AddBCC($news_mail.";");`
with
    `$mail_news->AddBCC($news_mail);`
because the method `addBCC()` handles the semicolon by itself. You do not need to specify by your own.